# How to create two relation in one prisma model?

Tags: mysql, orm, prisma

i have this model in prisma, i want that the match have two teams in it, and in Team have many Matches

```
model Team{
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    name String
    userId Int
    user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    homeMatches Match[] @relation("HomeTeam")
    awayMatches Match[] @relation("AwayTeam")
    @@index([userId])
}

model Match{
    id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
    date DateTime?
    homeTeamId Int
    homeTeam Team @relation("HomeTeam", fields: [homeTeamId], references: [id])
    awayTeamId Int
    awayTeam Team @relation("AwayTeam", fields: [awayTeamId], references: [id])
    homeScore Int
    awayScore Int
    @@index([homeTeamId])
    @@index([awayTeamId])
}
```

is this the right way to do it or there is a better way, a simpler way

Comment: It looks like your models are defined in the correct way, I would do it the same way.